# RegEx to Double Hyphens from URL

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match, substitution, regexp-replace

I've created a Google Spreadsheet that helps assist me in creating products for my company's website. We have a field that allows us to create the seo keyword part of the URL in relation to that particular product. So, ideally, the url would look like:
`www.example.com/gold-blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3.`

Excluding the domain, the spreadsheet only needs the SEO Keyword which is this:
`gold-blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3`. I would like to be able to filter out multiple characters, such as the ampersand, parenthesis, apostrophes, and double hyphens. I've completed all but the last one and I am stuck with this last bit.

My formula is:

> LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "-"),"[\&(\)/']",""))

The information currently comes from an adjacent column with the title of the product. Title being in this instance: `Gold & Blue Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3)`. I have tried multiple variations of the RegEx, and the substitute which ends up with something like:
`gold--blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3` where the ampersand gives me a double hyphen.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT VISUAL ADDITION**

[image: google sheets example of output]

**EDIT:** I didn't realize my quote didn't put my original escape characters in the initial formula, so this has been updated!

**Third Edit: Since I'm a newbie in terms of writing questions:**

| Input | Output | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gold & Blue Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | gold--blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 | gold-blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |
| Poppies Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | poppies-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |  |
| Calla Lilies Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | calla-lilies-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |  |
| The Flamingoes Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | the-flamingoes-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |  |
| Japanese Bridge Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | japanese-bridge-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |  |
| Van Gogh's Specialty Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3) | van-goghs-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3 |  |

Comment: This gives me the same response as posted. `gold--blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3`

Comment: I have added an image to for visual representation instead of just words.

Comment: I would've done something like this `=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A5,"\W+","-"))` and also another function to remove extra dashes from each end.

Comment: For future reference, always provide 5-10 inputs and expected outputs as a markdown table.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I have included a table with five examples, with four of them showing as per the original formula I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "-"), "[&\(\)\/']", ))
```

some stuff needs to be escaped with `\`

and maybe one more wrapper:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "-"), "[&\(\)\/']", ), "--", "-")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first one, but didn't think about trying another SUBSTITUTE function. Gosh. I totally missed that. 

The second one worked for my purpose!

Answer (score 3):

```
Gold & Blue Glass Ornament Collection (Set of 3)
```

after first substitute becomes:

```
Gold-&-Blue-Glass-Ornament-Collection-(Set-of-3)
```

When `[&()/']` is used, it removes `&()/'`, but `-&-` becomes `--`. To avoid this, just add `-` at the end:

```
[&()/']-
```

As a formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "-"),"[&()/']-",)
```

Without `SUBSTITUTE`, you can also use

```
[&()/' ]+
```

One or more(`+`) of `&` or `()` or `/` or  (space) or `'` to be replaced with one `-`

```
=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(C2,"[&()/ ']+","-"))
```

Comment: I appreciate your edits - I've tried each of your methods, and on an independent sheet with only my example, it works. 

With the sheet I'm using it on, the third solution provides me with `gold-blue-glass-ornament-collection-set-of-3-` where there is an extra hyphen at the end. I checked the title for any extra space, and there was none. (I also included the backslashes before the amp, parens.) For the lines with an apostrophe, it adds a hyphen there (where its not needed).

Comment: @dickinsonk9 [Backslashes are not needed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions).   The hyphen is present, because it replaces the last `)` with `-`. The substitute one shouldn't add the extra hyphen: `=REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "-"),"[&()/']-",)`.